# Return Checkbox states: Form with errors: PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I created a from with multiple required fields that the users my complete.  Then I also have 3 checkboxes of which the user must select at least one of them.  When the user submit the form I start doing the checks and each error I find I store in an array.  If there are any errors I display the errors for the user plus the form with the values that the user already entered.  This bit work fine.  I want to know how I would be able to return a checked checkbox if the user checked any of then and any amount, but none, fo them?  With from fields it's easy:

```
<input type="text" name="First_Name" value="<?php echo $First_Name; ?>" />
```

My question is in what way I would be able to get the result of my checkbox the user select?  My guess is that it might be something like:

```
if(isset())
```

But I am not sure.  Any help on this please?

Comment: `isset` should work. Did you try it? You could probably also use `array_key_exists`.

Comment: If I do you ` isset ` how would the code look like:

Comment: See @anonamas's answer -- that's how.

Comment: If I do you `isset` how would the code look like:
inline `<input type="checkbox" id="Forum_Access" class="Forum_Access" checked="???" />`

This is what I need to know plz?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1"<?php if (isset($_POST['check1'])) echo " checked"; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) { do this }

If the checkbox has been selected the if statement will run.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a checkbox, the "value" that has been given will be set. So if your value gets set into a database this probably will be a tinyint(1)

you should use the following:

```
<input type="text" name="aCheckBox" value="1" <?php if (@$_POST['aCheckBox']=="1") { echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />
```

The @-sign is supressing the notices, so you dont have to use isset. Isset is useless anyway, because some browsers send the field in the post array but without value. So the isset would ways return true.

Comment: the overuse of @ leads to some performance issues, i tend to avoid it except when i have to cope with a monster code. This is my "goto" of php :)

Comment: considering the question, i dont think the author doesn't need great performance. Ofcourse it would be best to use the inarray and check if the field is empty. But the thing is, that some browser tend to send an empty value with the correct key. So isset() would always return true since it's set.